# Sonarqube -how to get the key of a quality profile

Tags: key, profile, sonarqube

i want to get a list of all rules of a quality profile. In order to do that I first need to get the key (not the name) of this profile. Unfortunately this information can not be read by a simple ws call.
I'd be very happy if you could help me on this.

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score -1):

To make the answer available on stackoverflow as well: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Retrieving-the-key-of-a-quality-profile-tt5030042.html#a5030071